# How to make a single key that is both primary and foreign in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The code is what I tried previously the

```
create table DroppedPatients
(
    PatientKey nchar(15) not null,
    primary key (PatientKey),
    PatientKey nchar(15) not null references Patient(PatientKey)
)
```

However, I don't know how to make a single key as shown in the picture?

[image]

I am very new to SQL so I haven't tried much except for the normal reference / foreign key

Comment: I am currently using Microsoft SQL (t-sql) Management Studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible - try below query to get the desired result -

```
create table DroppedPatients
(
    PatientKey nchar(15) not null  primary key  foreign key  references Patient(PatientKey)
)
```

Comment: Although this would work, you should always name your constraints. This will create the constraints with random names and you will see a nightmare when you try to use upgrade scripts in deployed databases...

Comment: Thank you very much! For the life of me I couldn't figure what I was doing wrong. As in my previous comment if you have any recommendations for T-sql videos please let me know. Because I would like to learn more I just been using Udemy/ Youtube mainly. But if you know any good videos I'm open to them.

Answer (score 3):

You have two mistakes in the code you've posted.

The first one is that you've specified the `PatientKey` column twice - basically that's telling SQL Server that you are attempting to create a table with two columns that have the same name - naturally that's impossible to do.

Your second mistake is syntactical - you're missing some keywords.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```
CREATE TABLE DroppedPatients
(
    PatientKey NCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    DateDropped DATETIME2 NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_DroppedPatients_DateDropped DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
    ReasonDropped NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DroppedPatients PRIMARY KEY (PatientKey),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DroppedPatients_Patient FOREIGN KEY (PatientKey) REFERENCES Patient(PatientKey)
)
```

Please note it's best practice to always name your constraints.

Comment: My *plus-one* is especially for the remark **to always name your constraints**. I really don't know, why it is even possible to create unnamed constraints...

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I'm still pretty new to SQL so I'm not completely sure how constraints work. I been trying to read "Beginning Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Programming". If you know any good Youtube videos / Udemy classes that help with t-sql let me know. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I been wanting to continue with SQL but got stumped with that question.